# Specifying correct #include headers when developing a plugin

Tags: c++, eigen

I am writing a plugin which utilizes a custom library for a larger code application. The basic structure is:

Large code base -> plugin -> custom library

The larger code uses a library that I also use in my custom library (Eigen) but an older version. Because of this, some of the routines that I am trying to use will fail.

I have tried hiding all of the instances of up-to-date classes from the large code base which does ensure the plugin only uses the correct library as follows:

```cpp
#ifdef LIBCOMPILE
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<Eigen/Sparse>
#endif

#ifdef LIBCOMPILE
//Definitions and commands that use Eigen
#endif
```

However, when the large code base tries to instantiate my plugin I get SEGABRT errors which disappear when I comment out the offending sub-class. These appear to be due to memory allocation issues.

How can I expose classes in my custom library to the large code base but make sure that I'm using the correct library?

Comment: What versions of Eigen are you using? If you have to, pass the matrices C style and definitely don't mix versions of libraries at an interface. That's just asking for problems...

Comment: Are you able to recompile "large code base" with an up-to-date version of Eigen. Or can you compile your plugin with the same version of Eigen as the code base? Also, make sure that you use the same target instruction set (SSE/AVX/...) as well as the same custom compilation flags, for both compilation units.

Comment: Avi: My library is using Eigen's git mirror while the large codebase is using a very old version (I can't check at the moment for the exact version number). I tried using the C style interface but, since my Eigen matrices were members of a class that caused memory allocation problems. I was considering trying to use a pimpl approach to conceal my classes and hopefully avoid the allocation problem.

Comment: Chtz: Re-compiling the large code base ended up being the solution in my case. I needed newer features in Eigen than we're available in the old release. I haven't submitted an answer because I was hoping to see if anyone had another, more general, suggestion. I wasn't being careful with the flags or Target instructions so that could have been my problem too.